# proof L-smoothness of a convex & twice differentiable function

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

[image]

Hello , I have to show the following exercise included in the picture.  I have managed to show the backward (from 2 to 1 ) .I  simply used Taylor's theorem around y and then I  applied  the given inequality (2) and some linear algebra and got the (1) . Unfortunately, I am struggling with the other way  (from 1 to 2). Some solutions I found online use contradiction and some other steps that I do not really understand. If someone here can help by providing a simple proof for this part I would be grateful.

Comment: Not all of the notions you are using might be be generally known (to me definitively not). So you might consider adding at least a reference to your problem statement so that one is able to catch up with those definitions.

Answer (score 1):

To go from (1) to (2), notice that around any point $x$ we have

$$
\nabla f(y) = \nabla f(x) + \nabla^2 f(x)(y - x) + O(\|y - x\|^2).
$$

Now, plug in $y = x + tv$ for an arbitrary unit vector $v$. Then

$$
\nabla f(x + tv) - \nabla f(x) = t \nabla^2 f(x) v + O(t^2).
$$

Take an inner product on both sides with $v$, which gives

$$
\langle v, \nabla f(x + tv) - \nabla f(x)\rangle =
t \langle v, \nabla^2 f(x) v \rangle + O(t^2).
$$

Now, take absolute values on both sides and use smoothness of $f$ to upper bound the left hand side.

Can you see how to continue from there?